# bootstrap navbar isn't working on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I tried to squeeze and expand on my desktop browser and it works. But, when the file is hosted on my server and I access that URL on my phone it doesn't work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#" id="brand1">brand1<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="brand2">brand2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="brand3">brand3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="brand4">brand4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="brand5">brand5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: can you provide the url?

Comment: What phone and browser?

Comment: http://kovidgurrala.nfshost.com/

Comment: I'm using chrome on nexus 6p

Answer (score 1):

I missed the meta tag in the header for mobile compatibility.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```